# Oracle SQL: Group rows by identical fields without aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

I'm quite sure it's possible, but I can't quite remember how.

Consider following table:

```
A   B   C
1   1   A
1   2   A
1   2   B
2   1   C
2   2   A
2   2   B
2   2   C
```

I would like to present it as:

```
A   B   C
1   1   A
1   2   A
        B
2   1   C
2   2   A
        B
        C
```

In other words, group on a unique (A,B).
I was thinking along the lines of **GROUP BY ROLLUP**, but I can't really figure out how to just make rows null without a group by function.
(note: I imagine this has been asked before, but I just can't find the right search terms to find it. Thanks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table t
(a    number,
 b    number,
 c    varchar2(1));

insert into t values(1, 1, 'A');
insert into t values(1, 2, 'A');
insert into t values(1, 2, 'B');
insert into t values(2, 1, 'C');
insert into t values(2, 2, 'A');
insert into t values(2, 2, 'B');
insert into t values(2, 2, 'C');

select case when rn = 1
            then a
            else null end as a,
       case when rn = 1
            then b
            else null end as b,
       c
from (select a, b, c,
             row_number() over (partition by a, b order by c) as rn,
             row_number() over (order by  a, b, c) as rn_total
      from t)
order by rn_total;

A   B   C
-   -   -
1   1   A
1   2   A
        B
2   1   C
2   2   A
        B
        C
```

And finally, clean your test environment:

```
drop table t purge;
```

---

You can do it even without a subquery:

```
select case when row_number() over (partition by a, b order by c) = 1
            then a
            else null end as a,
       case when row_number() over (partition by a, b order by c) = 1
            then b
            else null end as b,
       c
from t
order by t.a, t.b, c ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e36eb/4)**